# FastAPI "cancel" doesn't terminate the script, and "execute" once again doesn't restart

Tags: web-services, fastapi, uvicorn

I try to build a web server that will run the script "main.py" when a user is authorized and when he enters the subpage "/api/run/". It works right now. But I would like to have 2 more functionalities here which I don't know how to implement.

- After clicking on "Execute" once again, I would like to restart the script running. It means it should stop and start once again. Now it works in a way that the first run is still executing and the second run starts which finally leads to 2 runnings at the same time.
- After clicking on "Cancel", I would like to terminate executing the script, but nothing happen and the script is still executing.

[image]

In a nutshell, the "main.py" script reads database records, finds the last record that wasn't modified, modifies its column, and set the value to "True". It has a while loop inside and when I run it locally, the next runnings of this script always start from the last unmodified record which is expected behavior. But when the script is executed from web server API, after executing once again, old running is still executing, and new running executes the script but this script doesn't start from the last unmodified record but start from the first record of the database what leads to duplicated records.

I tried out many things but nothing worked.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, BackgroundTasks, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials
from main import main
from config import Config
import secrets

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBasic()


def get_user(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    current_username = credentials.username.encode("utf8")
    correct_username = Config.fastapi('USERNAME').encode("utf8")
    is_correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(current_username, correct_username)

    current_password = credentials.password.encode("utf8")
    correct_password = Config.fastapi('PASSWORD').encode("utf8")
    is_correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(current_password, correct_password)

    if not (is_correct_username and is_correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username


@app.get("/api/run")
async def run_process(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
                      username: str = Depends(get_user)):
    background_tasks.add_task(main)
    if status.HTTP_200_OK == 200 and username:
        return {"200 OK": "Process has been executed successfully"}


@app.get("/users/me")
def read_current_user(username: str = Depends(get_user)):
    return {"username": username}
```

I would be very grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: if u want to stope code execution then use raise exception where u want to stop the execution of code.